CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is invalid default value for DATE type in Mysql
I need to set up a default value for the Date type column in Mysql.
The SQL looks like:
ALTER TABLE `playlist_statistics_history` CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;

But this throws me an error: Invalid default value for date.
Can somebody tell me what is valid default value for the DATE type is?

As stated in duplicate, add paretheses around DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

It does not work. Its sad...

Just tried this successfully: ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) NOT NULL; on mysql server 8.0.39

I am on 5.7.33. May be thats the problem. I tried the same sql.
